# What does the contextsField do

Tags: lucene

I'm implementing Lucene Autosuggest and trying to find out what the contextsField do in a DocumentDictionary?

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on it?

Answer (score 0):

**contextsField** is a string field which specifies from where to read contexts from. It is used to specify the associated contexts.

Here Context is a enumerator which specifies the context in which the Directory is being used for.

Comment: Ok, I still don't get it. Can you give an example? The code suggests that it can be used to filter suggestions.